# Get all Active Session in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have  custom authentication provider and custom authentication handler for spring security with custom user class which implements the UserDetails interface.
Now I want all active user list in my application.
I have added below code in web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

below code in app-context.xml

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

below code in security.xml

```
<session-management>
        <concurrency-control
            session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"  />
    </session-management>
```

And in my controller I have used

```
@Autowired
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
List<Object> allPrincipal = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    System.out.println(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size());
```

The result of System.out.println is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a duplicated question : [sessionRegistry is empty when I use ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy instead of ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463022/sessionregistry-is-empty-when-i-use-concurrentsessioncontrolauthenticationstrate), but the most common issue is usually loading the spring context twice. Check that you don't have an annotation-based context and an applicationContext.xml as well.

Comment: In my controller I have also used @autowired SessionRegistry sessionRegistry; Is this not the correct way?