# Spring Security multiple logged users fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am making a basic Tic tac toe Project with Spring , Spring Security and Hibernate. Application can save game for each logged user in database and allow to load it whenever we want. That is not a problem , but it appears when it comes to multi-threading. When i run single application in single browser window everything is working good. But when i open another window , two players are playing the same game.

I know it may be caused by bean singletons created by Spring but I am sure that it is not. To check currently logged user, i made an method to get him from SecurityContextHolder

```
private User getUserFromSpringContext() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = authentication.getName();
    System.out.println("Currently logged users = " + name);
    return userService.findUserByUsername(name);
}
```

When multiple users are logged in , that metod prints name of only one of them. I have no idea why. Here are some important  code lines my Security configuration and userDetails classes:

Security Configuration:

```
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    builder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return auth;
}
```

Custom Users Details Service

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAuthoriries(user));
}

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthoriries(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getRole()));
    return authorities;
}
```

Does anybody knows cause of this problem?

During testing that I came up with another problem. When i click Logout , all users are logged out. I am posting here rest of my Spring Security Configuration.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/start", "/", "/login", "/registry","/success","/new").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: assuming it works the way i think it does, have you asserted (however) that as users log in, their entries are created in your database? perhaps it only works for the very first user only?

Comment: I edited post because i found another issue.

Comment: Define opening a new window? If you that is pressing CTRL+T or CTRL+N from you existing browser that is not a new browser. The session state, cache and cookies will be copied. You are actually not playing with multiple players but with a single user in multiple browser windows. I would say it works as it should and you are just testing it in the wrong way.

Comment: Only if i open two different browsers like Chrome and Edge , my app works correctly. So does it means that everything is fine but i should always run it in multiple browsers?

Answer (score 3):

`SecurityContextHolder` gives you access to the security context associated with the *current thread*, thus only the *current* user - the one whose request triggered the call to `getAuthentication()`, so it's behaving exactly the way it should.

If you, on the other hand, want all active sessions (i.e. all logged in users) you should inject the `SessionRegistry` and call `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()` on it.

The details are already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272193/294657).