# How to set @Scheduled for each 30 min and calling sa method with parameters?

Tags: java, spring

I have a case where I need to use Scheduled.
This schedule will execute this method every 30 min, so the method is

```
    @Transactional
    public void processEnable()
            throws Exception
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.warn("[Enable] [STATUS] - ERROR  ");
            logger.warn("[Enable] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

and I want to get this method to execute for 30 min

and i am doing this with that.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1-2 * * *")
public void Enable()
{
    try
    {
        Service.Enable();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the problem is how to get the parameter here, is my first time, in fact, using @Scheduled and I don't know how it works or how can I get the parameter from the user so I can get this method works each 30 min.

I am having no idea to get the parameter I want.

Comment: So, you want to call `processEnableApp` method after you receive those parameters, don't you? Plus, is it gonna be done for 1 user or multiple? Because you only have 1 scheduler, I think.

Comment: is an app for multiple users who can  have  1  or multiple apps, that's why I need the parameters to get the correct app in this case

Comment: You can actually, autowire the Scheduler to the class you need. Move those parameters to the `processEnableApp` method, and call the scheduler whenever you want. However, not sure, if the scheduling will be kicked in in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comments a lot @MensurQulami but  I mean still, I don't get it how will I get parameters, I am used to getting them from API that is being called, Sorry but still doesn't understand this.

Comment: Don't you understand getting parameters for Scheduler or getting parameters in general?

Comment: No no, just getting parameters from Scheduler, I meant by API to specific that I get them from frontend when a user does something, but as Scheduler  is an automatic process I don't know how to get them

Comment: And what I suggest is trying to trigger the Scheduler manually. You can autowire it. Then change the method to `Scheduler.processEnableApp(Integer idLang, Integer idApp, Authentication userAuthenticated)`. Now you can pass the parameters. All you need to do is to call it from the class you need. But as I said, I am not sure if it will 100% work.

Comment: I mean I want a Scheduler cause I don't want to go at the page and do it manually, in this case, I can just add an extra API, for example, and call it each time the page is reloaded but I want to use Scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Scheduled method:

1. you need to set the user executing the code to get spring security annotations satisfied. So using a system user do:

```java
SecurityContext securityContext= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);
```

2. get all the authenticated users at the moment the job starts running. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272193/2743585)

```java
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
```

3. iterate the list of Authentication objects from the previous step and call `processEnableApp` (passing the parameters to the method)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the external objects to be used within your `@Scheduled` methods, you should inject them into the `DemoService` class using autowiring rather than passing them as parameters to the `@Scheduled` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression is wrong. You need this `*/30 * * * *`